# Setting selected value on DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I'm attempting to set the selected value of a combobox depending on what the controller has set.

My DropDownListFor:

```
@if (Model.FormType == "Detailed")
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FormType,
    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(FormType))),
    "Detailed")
}
else
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FormType,
    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(FormType))),
    "Summary")
}
```

My FormType enum:

```
  public enum FormType
  {
    Summary,
    Detailed
  }
```

When I try this, it's duplicating "Summary" again and selecting it so I end up with duplicate entries:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your "Detailed" or "Summary" just a title of dropdown list. You can change it to "Select" for example. But if you need to show a selected item :

You need an util to create a SelectList

```
public static SelectList GetSelectList(string selectedText)
{
    Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FormType));
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var i in values)
    {
        
        var item=new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(FormType), i),
            Value =  i. ToString()
        };
        if(item.Text==selectedText) item.Selected=true;
        items.Add(item);
    }
    return new SelectList(items);
}
```

Add SelectList to your view model:

```
public Model ()
{
   ..... your code
 public  SelectList SelectList {get; set;}
{
```

after this you can put this code in your action

```
 model.SelectList=GetSelectList(model.FormType);
```

and finaly the view:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FormType, model.SelectList,"Select")
```